# Add text inside a box inside another box

Tags: color, mdframed, tcolorbox

**Problem:**

Trying to create a label for programming code by using text inside a color box inside another color box. However, I am not sure of the best practices regarding putting one box inside the other.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.5, 1, 0, 0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=editorLightGray]
        PHP
    \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

This code produce the following outcome:

[image]

**Desired outcome:**
[image]
**Update**
[image]

Any advice pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Man that is beautifully formatted question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way using `tcolorbox` (which uses `tikz` in the backend)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.5, 1, 0, 0}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\raggedleft\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=editorLightGray]
        PHP
    \end{mdframed}


\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,right=5pt,colback=editorLightGray,arc=0pt,auto outer arc]
\RaggedLeft\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,coltext=white,colback=editorPurple,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,width=1.5cm,boxsep=0pt,left=5pt,right=5pt,halign=center]
\bfseries PHP
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox} % outer box

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,right=5pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=editorLightGray,arc=0pt,auto outer arc]
\RaggedLeft\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,coltext=white,colback=magenta,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,width=1.5cm,boxsep=0pt,left=5pt,right=5pt,halign=center]
\bfseries PHP
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox} % outer box


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Now as a command with a lot of control options etc.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.5, 1, 0, 0}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newlength{\titleboxwidth}

\newtcolorbox{codelanguagebox}[2][]{boxrule=0pt,coltext=white,colback=magenta,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,width={#2},boxsep=0pt,left=5pt,right=5pt,halign=center,#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codelabel}{O{}mO{}}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,right=5pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=editorLightGray,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,#1]
    \setlength{\titleboxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}%
    \RaggedLeft\begin{codelanguagebox}[add to width=0.5cm,#3]{\the\titleboxwidth}
      \bfseries #2%
    \end{codelanguagebox}%
  \end{tcolorbox}   %
}


\begin{document}

\codelabel{PHP}

\codelabel{MySQL}

\codelabel[colback=blue]{MySQL}[colback=yellow,coltext=black]

\codelabel{C++}

\codelabel{\LaTeXe}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Last update**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.5, 1, 0, 0}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\titleboxwidth}

\newtcolorbox{codelanguagebox}[2][]{boxrule=0pt,coltext=white,colback=magenta,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,width={#2},boxsep=0pt,halign=center,valign=center,left=5pt,right=5pt,nobeforeafter,#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codelabel}{O{}mO{}}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,right=5pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=editorLightGray,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,#1]
    \setlength{\titleboxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}%
    \RaggedLeft\begin{codelanguagebox}[add to width=0.5cm,#3]{\the\titleboxwidth}
      \bfseries #2%
    \end{codelanguagebox}%
  \end{tcolorbox}   %
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\twocodelabels}{O{}mO{}mO{}}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,right=5pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=editorLightGray,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,#1]
    \RaggedLeft%
    \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\titleboxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}%
      \begin{codelanguagebox}[add to width=0.5cm,#3]{\the\titleboxwidth}
      \bfseries #2%
    \end{codelanguagebox} 
    \begin{codelanguagebox}[#3,colback={gray}]{0.75cm}%
      \bfseries +
    \end{codelanguagebox} 
    \setlength{\titleboxwidth}{\widthof{#4}}%
    \begin{codelanguagebox}[#3,add to width=0.5cm,#5]{\the\titleboxwidth}%
      \bfseries #4%
    \end{codelanguagebox}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}





\begin{document}
\codelabel{MySQL}
\codelabel{\scshape \huge PHP}
\codelabel{MySQL}[colback=editorPurple,coltext=black]
\twocodelabels{\ttfamily HTML}[height=0.6cm,colback=blue]{CSS}[colback=editorPurple]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will update with a better version

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Is there a way to make the color box adjustable to the text? If I write for instance "MySQL" then the text shifts to the right. In addition, how do I control the height of the grey box?

Comment: @kexxcream: I am just about to do that ;-)

Comment: @kexxcream: See my update please

Comment: I'm only getting the error message: /PHP.tex:67: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/halign', to which you passed 'center', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. - what could be wrong here?

Comment: @kexxcream: Which `tcolorbox` version do you have? I've used the latest 3.61 version. The `halign` key is an addition Thomas Sturm made in early May

Comment: Hope I can ask for some patience, but how do I found out which version I have? More importantly, how do I update it?

Comment: Depending on your distribution I would look for a file called `tcolorbox.sty`. Open it with the favourite editor and look at the top line. There should be something like `tcolorbox version 3. ...`. Updating depends on your distribution as well. But you can remove the `halign=center` stuff as well from the updated code (the 2nd solution)

Comment: Worked like a charm, it was located in /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ - updated it and the errors were gone. One final question, why is it that the text don't automatically adjust when I apply a font (size, type, etc) to it? Try for instance \ttfamily

Comment: @kexxcream: Where do you do the adjustments? `\codelabel{\ttfamily \huge PHP}` works for me

Comment: Sorry about that, it does work. Is it possible to add two more boxes after the purple box? I updated the desired outcome.

Comment: @kexxcream: Well, you're now editing the question away from the usual request -- this wasn't the deal ;-)

Comment: My apologies, should I post a new question? Not sure what the appropriate procedure is.

Comment: @kexxcream: The appropiate procedure is to post the requirements right from the start, not adding one after another one, trickle by trickle ... ;-) I will try, but I won't add another stuff afterwards

Comment: Thanks, I'll be careful next time. This came after the fact. I highly appreciate your effort.

Comment: @kexxcream: See my **final** update (apart from possible errors) please

Comment: Thank you kindly, I managed to get it to work. While I don't expect an update, I thought it might be useful for you to know that the three boxes (HTML + CSS) prints out stacked on top of each other.

Comment: @kexxcream: I doubt that, since I posted the screen shot of what I got. They are next to each other ;-) Use the full new example, not only the `\twocodelabels` command

Comment: You are right. I guess it's one of my other two packages (`\usepackage{upquote}` and `\usepackage{listings}`) that is messing it up.

Comment: @kexxcream: Please note, that `tcolorbox` also has a nice interface for code listings, it uses `listings` in the backend, but can be configured to use `minted` as well